# When using eGit, is there a way to compare two versions of a file in the history tree?

Tags: git, compare, history, egit

Note I am not asking to compare a version in the history with the working tree version. I'd like to know if there is a way to select a version in the history tree and compare it to the previous version in the tree (for example). I recall being able to do this with Mercurial.

Comment: No idea about eGit, but the way to do this in Git is `git diff <old-hash>..<new-hash> -- <file>`.

Answer (score 0):

You can compare differences between commits by selecting your item of interest in the **Project Explorer** (e.g. file, package, the whole project, etc.) and bringing up its **History** view with **Context menu -> Team -> Show in History**.

**Click** on one of the commit entries you wish to compare and **CTRL-Click** on the second commit to compare. **Right-Click** one of the two chosen entries and select **Compare with Each Other**. The resulting **Compare** view displays both a **Structure Compare** and **Java Source Compare** allowing you to examine changes at the file level and file content level.

Comment: Thanks very much. I completely missed that.